# UITable View is filling the entire view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, interface-builder, storyboard

I am working on an iphone application on XCode 4.3 using storyboard.

I have created a view and I need it to be divided in two parts. the top part will contain a UIImageView and the bottom part a UItableView. 
So I added both to the view using the storyboard interface builder, and set the sizes and positions of the UIImageView and the UITableView.

However when I run the application, the UITableView will take the entire view (it is being scaled to fill the view). I need it just to stay at the width/height I specified in the IB.

Why does the UITableView take the entire view? and how can I make a view with a UITableView be a small part of the view and not fill it?

I hope I was clear
Thanks a lot for any help

**edit:**

Screenshot of the storyboard section

[image: screenshot]

the top part has a UIImageView and a "Share" Button
and the bottom part a UITableView
The UITableView is taking the entire view and hidding the rest

Another screenshot requested

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this section of your storyboard: http://i.imgur.com/tGq5M.png

Comment: sorry didn't notice you needed that section. Added the screenshot requested

Comment: What's the autoresizing mask on UITableView? Make sure height resizing is off.

Comment: @0xSina where can I find that feature? thanks

Comment: Just a sanity check, but your code is referencing a `UIViewController` subclass, not `UITableView` directly, right? Something similar to this happened to me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using storyboard here, just a xib, but it should matter. This is how you should set it up:

**Autoresizing for UITableView:**
[image]

**Autoresizing for UIImageView:**
[image]

Notice the fixed top margin for image view, fixed bottom margin for tableview, and flexible height for both. This will ensure tableview always sticks to the bottom and expands upwards proportionally, and vice versa for image view.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to play around with this settings of your `UITableView`

I believe the setting is off making it resize. But I might be wrong.

[image]

Note: this is a screenshot of my UITableView inside a view controller and it is NOT filling my screen. It may have a different setting in your case. So play around with the values in there.

Comment: I have the same configuration as you but still not working :(

Comment: It seem your problem is pretty hard to reproduce for us to help out. I would highly recommend to smash the code and rebuild your view. Basically bring a new UIViewController and wire it to the class you are using to manage it. Make sure you get all the IBOutlet and properties set. See if this help. Also what would be helpful to get help is post your class files on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com).